# Oracle update statement with group function

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have some problem with Oracle Update statement with group function 
 I want to update a column all records from another table. 
 But it shows SQL Error: **ORA-01427**: single-  row subquery returns more than one row
 **Here is my example .**

```
create table branch_cp
(
area varchar2 (5) ,
branch_code varchar2 (5) primary key,
branch_name varchar2 (20));
------
create table branch_cp_2
(
area varchar2 (5) ,
branch_code varchar2 (5) primary key,
branch_name varchar2 (20));
----------------------------------
insert into branch_cp values ('01', '01', 'A');
insert into branch_cp values ('01', '02', 'B');
insert into branch_cp values ('03', '03', 'C');
----------
insert into branch_cp_2 values ('01', '04', 'D');
insert into branch_cp_2 values ('01', '05', 'E');
insert into branch_cp_2 values ('03', '06', 'F');
----------------------
select * from branch_cp;
------------------
update branch_cp
set branch_cp.branch_code = (select branch_cp_2.branch_code
from branch_cp_2
where branch_cp.area =branch_cp_2.area)
where exists (select 1 from branch_cp_2 where branch_cp_2.area = branch_cp.area) ;
```

How to use Group Function in  update statement. Please Help

Comment: area is a primary key column brach_cp_2 , your insert should fail as you are inserting same value 01 twice.

Comment: Sorry it was typed mistake. Branch is a primary key

Comment: Well, you have two `branch_cp_2` records where `area` is `01`. So how would you decide which of the two `branch_code` values for each of the two `branch_cp` rows with that area? You've said you want to group but you'd need to state what you want - the min or max code? Both records would get the same value then, which would violate your primary key.

Comment: Ok. i want to update when `area` `01` with `branch` `01` from `branch_cp` will update by `area` `01` with `branch` `03` from `branch_cp_2` . Next  `area` `01` with `branch` `02` from `branch_cp` will update by `area` `01` with `branch` `04` from `branch_cp_2`. Is it possible !!

Comment: Will there always be an equal number of records for each area, in both tables?

Comment: Yes...Actually, these records are as like **Single area with with multiple branches**. So under one area code I have multiple branches with the same area code. I have another table with area_code, area_name . Area_code reference to the Branch_cp/Branch_cp_2 area column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two records in each table where `area` is `01`, and you need to set them to different values to satisfy the primary key - you can't set them both to the max or min value from the second table, so you don't really want to do any grouping.

There doesn't seem to be any other ordering between records with the same `area`, so I'll assume it's arbitrary and it doesn't matter which record for each `area` gets which `branch_code` from the other table. If it isn't arbitrary then the rules would need to be specified...

A correlated update is tricky if you need to match on an arbitrary order within a group of records. You need some way to identify the row order, but adding a `row_number()` column to the original tables to create an inline view will lead to an ORA-01732 error.

You can, though, use the target table's `rowid` pseudocolumn; you just have to do an additional join in the correlation to get that same value along with the new `branch_code`. Something like:

```
select bc.rid,
  bc.area,
  bc.branch_code,
  bc.branch_name,
  bc2.area,
  bc2.branch_code,
  bc2.branch_name
from (
  select bc.*,
    bc.rowid as rid,
    row_number() over (partition by bc.area order by bc.branch_code) as rn
  from branch_cp bc
) bc
join (
  select bc2.*,
    row_number() over (partition by bc2.area order by bc2.branch_code) as rn
  from branch_cp_2 bc2
) bc2
on bc2.area = bc.area
and bc2.rn = bc.rn;
```

Which gives you:

```
RID                AREA  BRANCH_CODE BRANCH_NAME AREA  BRANCH_CODE BRANCH_NAME
------------------ ----- ----------- ----------- ----- ----------- -----------
AAAwy+AAEAAAA0DAAA 01    01          A           01    04          D           
AAAwy+AAEAAAA0DAAB 01    02          B           01    05          E           
AAAwy+AAEAAAA0DAAC 03    03          C           03    06          F
```

Now you don't actually need all those columns, you only need the `rid` (the `branch_cp.rowid`) and the correlated `branch_cp_2.branch_code`.

But you also only want to update when there is a match - to void nulling any rows where there is no value in the other table - so you would have to repeat that join in the `exists` subquery.

It's simpler to do a `merge`:

```
merge into branch_cp bc
using (
  select bc.rid,
      bc2.branch_code
    from (
      select bc.*,
        bc.rowid as rid,
        row_number() over (partition by bc.area order by bc.branch_code) as rn
      from branch_cp bc
    ) bc
    join (
      select bc2.*,
        row_number() over (partition by bc2.area order by bc2.branch_code) as rn
      from branch_cp_2 bc2
    ) bc2
    on bc2.area = bc.area
    and bc2.rn = bc.rn
) bc2
on (bc.rowid = bc2.rid)
when matched then update set bc.branch_code = bc2.branch_code;

3 rows merged.
```

Your table now has:

```
select * from branch_cp;

AREA  BRANCH_CODE BRANCH_NAME
----- ----------- -----------
01    04          A           
01    05          B           
03    06          C
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4f6c/1).

Comment: Wow..Thanks a lot. It's totally helpful for me. I have also tried adding a new matching row in both tables. And it works. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @K_islam: Please accept this answer if it works for you.